# Android Kotlin: Mocking a free function using Mockito/PowerMock

Tags: android, mockito, kotlin, powermock, android-testing

I am having a free function in Kotlin that I want to mock for test purpose.

My free function is something like this:

```
fun somethingAwesomeIsDoneHere(param: String) : String {
    // Awesome
}
```

In my test I want to mock/stub it so that when it is called a mock value is returned.

```
when(somethingAwesomeIsDoneHere(something)).thenReturn(retValue)
```

Even if it could be done with PowerMock please do let me know.

PS: I am using Kotlin 1.0.1-2 for my project.

Comment: I doubt it is possible with Mockito, AFAIK, you can only mock methods inside an open class or interface.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that with Mockito but I think it can be done with PowerMock. Let's assume that `somethingAwesomeIsDoneHere()` is located in `File.kt`. Then you have to mock the `FileKt` class and it's static method:

```
mockStatic(FileKt::class.java)
expect(somethingAwesomeIsDoneHere(something)).andReturn(retValue)
replay(FileKt::class.java)
```

Comment: I am not able to access the class `FileKt` into my Kotlin tests. Though surprisingly to me I am able to do so in my Java tests!

Comment: @Abdullah Yep, seems `FileKt` is inaccessible from Kotlin tests. I think you can file an issue to https://kotl.in/issue

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You have to annotate a test with `@PrepareForTest(FileKt::class)`, which is impossible do achieve with `Class.forName()`.

Comment: If you happen to have all of your files in a common package, you can get the `@PrepareForTest` to pick them up via the fullyQualifiedNames mechanism: `@PrepareForTest(NormalClass::class, NormalClass2::class, fullyQualifiedNames=arrayOf("com.x.y.z.utils.*"))`