# Android Mockito - Mocking a function return value

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, android-testing, android-unit-testing

Amateur question, but I can't seem to find an answer...

I am writing unit tests using Mockito and I have a utils function (`isOnline(context)`) which checks if I am offline before making a network call.

I am not trying to test that function, so I want to mock the result of that function and not run any of the code within it.

I've tried two of my usual approaches:

- `given(isOnline(context)).willReturn(true)`
- `when(isOnline(application)).thenReturn(true)`

But both seem to be running the `isOnline` method.

```
fun isOnline(context: Context): Boolean {
  val connectivityManager = context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
...
}
```

... and I am getting the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type 
 android.net.ConnectivityManager
    at org.triggerise.base.utils.NetworkUtilsKt.isOnline(NetworkUtils.kt:14)
```

Any suggestions on how to just mock the result without running the contents of the method?

Answer (score 0):

That's the way Java/Kotlin works - you're actually calling the method while mocking the behaviour there, so the code is executed. To work around that, you need to use [doReturn](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12) (section 12. in the docs) Mockito method.

```java
doReturn(false).when(mockedObject).isOnline(context)
```

If the method is static, you have to use [mockStatic](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks) method (section 48. in the docs).

```java
try (var mockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(YourClass.class) {
    mockedStatic.when(() -> YourClass.isOnline(...)).thenReturn(false);

    // rest of the test 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonasz! 

What if there is no object associated with the function? My isOnline function is a 'free standing' function part of a util.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with Mockito, unfortunately: [GitHub](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin/issues/277), [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37521384/android-kotlin-mocking-a-free-function-using-mockito-powermock).